# UIButton with a custom asymmetric clickable region?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an image with various asymmetric regions, is it possible to place a button above each region?

The image will be something similar to this: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1557638/screenshots/4367307/proactive_d.png

Comment: Please post image or code whatever you have.

Comment: @SagarChauhan no code, since I'm not sure how I should approach this. But I've edited the question to include an example image

Comment: here is a rough idea. Make you image with SVG format, then convert the svg into UIBezierPaths, then detect touches for separate enclosed shapes

Comment: @sj-r Can you please show an example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After way too much research, I’ve decided to go with following solution for an image with multiple asymmetric clickable regions:

Duplicated the image file, colored each region with a different color, and stored as an asset.

Placed a simple tap gesture recognition over the displayed image. When tapped, I get the relative coordinate to the displayed image.

Get the color from the map image at the tapped coordinates. 
Compare to a predefined enum.